# if [ -e $1]; then... not working

Tags: linux, shell

trying to make a regex treatment with shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -e $1]; then
    echo "if\n"
else
    echo $1
fi
```

execute with `sh ./prepereTxt.sh ./bview.txt`
and gets:

```
./prepereTxt.sh: 3: [: missing ]
./bview.txt
```

Comment: Spacing around `[` and `]` are important. `[` is a command, not a language construct.

Comment: If you'd run this through http://shellcheck.net/, you wouldn't be needing to ask us here.

Comment: (Also, what does this have to do with "regex" at all?)

Answer (score 0):

Space is missing "`[ -e $1<SPACE_MISSING>]`"

```
#!/bin/sh

    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        echo "if\n"
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
```

Comment: You haven't fixed the spacing issue in your answer, *or* addressed the quoting issues (which would also prevent it from working correctly with all inputs).

Answer (score 0):

Add space before and after rectangular brackets.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e $1 ]; then
  echo "if"
else
  echo "$1"
fi
```

Comment: Correct as far as it goes, but not sufficient. What if the filename given in `$1` contains whitespace, or a literal wildcard character?

Comment: (Also, what was up with the original formatting, with huge amounts of whitespace between "lines" of code which, AFAICT, had no actual newlines between them?)